# How can I create a dynamic two dimensional array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am using c++ in my lesson and for solving a program I should create an array that may be change in dimensions. 
For example:

```
{
    int I,J;
    cin>>I;
    cin>>J;
    double X[I][J];
    double B[I][J];
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, that container is specifically designed for this use case.

Answer (score 5):

As always with dynamic arrays, use `std::vector`:

```
unsigned I, J;
std::cin >> I >> J;
if (!std::cin) {
    // handle error
}
std::vector<double> X(I * J);
```

To get/set the element at index (`i`, `j`):

```
X.at(i * J + j) = 1;
std::cout << X.at(i * J + j);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to have a allocated and initialized 2 dimensional dynamic array in c++ use `std::vector`like this:

```
#include <vector>   

int I,J;
cin>>I;
cin>>J;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> X( I, std::vector<double>( J, 0.0 ) );
```

The constructer reserves and initializes as many elements you want.
Yo can access to it with `operator []`, `vector::size` gives you the number of elements in.

Anyway you should prefer the solution of Elyse.

Comment: Hello again to all my friends
I do not think I have thanks to my friends so much. I replied that this question very much.
I was not familiar with the vectors that you've met me with vectors.

thanks a lot